# Что выбрать: autolayout или отдельный .xib?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Привет!

По неопытности сделал приложение только для 4-дюймовых экранов. Теперь встал вопрос: Как оптимизировать приложение для iPhone 4-4s?

Вижу 2 пути решения:

1. Включить на всех экранах autolayout(они были выключены). В вьюшках очень много кода написано для кастомизации контролов и т.д(например, изменение высоты UITextField). Не помешает ли это нормальной настройке autolayout'ов?
2. Создать отдельный .xib-файл для iPhone 4-4s. В данном случае, я даже не могу представить как это реализовать. Как я понял, нужно проверить высоту экрана и в зависимости от этого, грузить нужный мне .xib. В какой метод прописывать эту проверку, в viewDidLoad? Как подгружать .xib?

Какой вариант предпочтительней?
Спасибо:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу пути 1 точно не скажу т.к. autolayout у меня всегда отключены (везде была нужна поддержка iOS5, а их там нет) , по идее авторасстановка той же высоты вполне может поломать автолейаут, что именно произойдет точно не скажу, тут зависит от его реализации - либо возможно перекрытие элементов если он применяется один раз, либо что вероятнее лейауты будут портить изменение размеров (хотя они вроде бы не меняют размер, только положение на форме)

По поводу пункта 2 - так ведь если вы меняете размеры вручную, то тоже еще вопрос как оно будет сочитаться. Сам по себе технически этот путь реализуется довольно просто - заводятся два ксиба, далее в init вашего потомка UIViewController прописываете что-то на подобие:

```
if (is4inchDevice)
   self = [super initWithNibName:@"iPhone5XibName" bundle:nil];
else
   self = [super initWithNibName:@"iPhone4XibName" bundle:nil];
```

где is4inchDevice макрос определения размера экрана

```
#define is4inchDevice ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
```

Comment: В итоге все сделал через автолейауты, т.к. у меня приложение для иос >=6.0. Оказывается удобная вещь:)